# How to transform a number array to objects array before setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that I am trying to set the value for from a different array however my arrays are not similar the array I am trying to set should look like this
expanded = [id1, id2, id3]
while the array I am setting from looks more like this

data = [{id: 1, name:"test"},{id:2, name:"test2"},{id:3, name:"test3"}]

not sure how to do this with this.setState

Comment: So what data are you trying to get from the second array? Is it the combination of the first property and value i.e "id1, id2 ..." or what? I need to be sure of the data you're trying to get so I can help you.

Comment: Can you provide a more tangible example of the first array with values to the second array of objects? SO also isn't a code writing service, so please also include any attempts of doing this on your own first, it may help us refine an answer. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `let arr = data.map(item => item.id)` to just get the ids, then `this.setState({state: arr})`. This will transform the array formatted like `[{id: 1, name:"test"},{id:2, name:"test2"},{id:3, name:"test3"}]` to `[id1, id2, id3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
const [array, setArray] = useState(data.map(ítem => item.id))
```

Or, if you are using clase components:

```
this.state = {
   array: data.map(item => item.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const expanded = [1, 2, 3]
const data = expanded.map((e)=>(
  {id: e, name: `test${e-1 ? e : '' }`} 
))

// here you can use setState()
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make your desired array from the second array. And then use that array in your state.

```js
const data = [{id: 1, name:"test"},{id:2, name:"test2"},{id:3, name:"test3"}];
const desiredArray = data.map(item=> Object.keys(item)[0]+item.id );
console.log(desiredArray);
```

This code snippet will give you the array that you have mentioned you require in your project. Then setState on it accordingly.